# Jboss 7.1.1 java ws client java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

I'm working with Jboss 7.1.1 and I have a client soap web service that works in Tomcat but when I deploy in Jboss I have many errors and I don't understand why it is not working in jboss.

I also tried other versions of jboss and I have the same problem.

After many tries now i have this error:

```
09:16:39,905 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rci_pcd]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.BccWsResponseVO com.rcibanque.pcd.client.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpc.getEngagementBCC(com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.PcdWsRequestVO)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.rcibanque.socle.server.filter.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:42) [rci-socle-18.4.04_DEV.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:236) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:163) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.ws.bcc.BCCWsServiceService.<init>(BCCWsServiceService.java:44) [classes:]
    at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpcImpl.getEngagementBCC(BCCServiceRpcImpl.java:28) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    ... 22 more

09:16:39,909 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rci_pcd]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.BccWsResponseVO com.rcibanque.pcd.client.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpc.getEngagementBCC(com.rcibanque.pcd.shared.beans.viewobject.bcc.PcdWsRequestVO)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.rcibanque.socle.server.filter.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:42) [rci-socle-18.4.04_DEV.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:236) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:163) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85) [cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.ws.bcc.BCCWsServiceService.<init>(BCCWsServiceService.java:44) [classes:]
    at com.rcibanque.pcd.server.service.bcc.BCCServiceRpcImpl.getEngagementBCC(BCCServiceRpcImpl.java:28) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561) [gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar:]
```

Does anyone has an idea about this?

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: yeah!, and i can't understand why ? and why also it works in tomcat and not in jboss...